# Encypt Conncetion string in Bean

Tags: java, encryption

I am new to Java. My requirement is to Encrypt a database connections string. 
I know that Encryption is used hide user id and login credentials. But in my case I didn't find any database connection string. I find below line of code related to server

```html
<property name="iName" value=java:/iABC"/>
```

Client is asking us to encrypt a connection string.

What I have to answer to the client, there is no any database credential's to encrypt?

Please suggest me..